# How to check for errors on field in custom form helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I know Simple Form plugin achieves it (unfortunately I don't wanna use simple form).

If input field has errors associated with it, it is wrapped in div with `.field_with_errors` class. Also using form_for helper default/current values are all set automatically.

Here's `text_field` helper:

```
def text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
```

How do I check for errors if all I got is `object_name`?

I tried `@object`, `instance_eval`, none have seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

i think its: `self.object` or just `self`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. I used a custom form builder (and configured the application to use it by default), so I could set the defaults on all my forms. I overrode the `text_field` and checked the errors hash on the object.

```
class ApplicationFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def text_field(method, options = {})
    if @object.errors.include?(method)
      # add some error classes to options[:class]
    end
    super(method, options)
  end
end
```